# Narrowing a resultset by comparison of records

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi i have this resultset from a query to a X table

```
1 | JOHN
2 | JOHN D
3 | JOHN D.
4 | JOHN DO
5 | JOHN DOE
6 | JOHN DD
7 | JOHN DOE.
8 | JOHNY
```

I need to narrow this result set to only one result among this coincidences i need to take as a valid result the most coincident record. So i thought the correct algorithm for this would be like this:

1. Check the first word coincidence among records from left to right ( JOHN [seven times])
2. Check the second word coincidence among records from left to right ( DOE [twice] )
3. Determine "JOHN DOE" is the most repeated value, OK

Comment: Your example is wrong - the most repeated value is JOHN DO (three times). So am I right or you need JOHN DOE in any case?

Comment: That's right knagaev JOHN DO is the most repeated value not JOHN DOE its my mistake but the idea is the same

Comment: so you need to get JOHN DO as the result of the example?

Comment: But  if we continue the right answer will be JOHN D (six times). What is the right answer?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is computationally expensive.  The approach I would take is a self-join on the fields to see the overlap from each field compared to every other:

```
select x.name, count(*)
from x cross join
     x x2
where left(x.name, length(x.name)) = left(x2.name, length(x.name))
group by x.name
order by count(*) desc
```

I notice that you are getting a count of 7 for "John" instead of "8".  I suspect that you don't want to match "Johny".  For that, let's add an additional clause:

```
select x.name, count(*)
from x cross join
     x x2
where left(x.name, length(x.name)) = left(x2.name, length(x.name)) and
      (length(x.name = x2.name) or substr(x2.name, length(x.name)+1, 1) = ' ')
group by x.name
order by count(*) desc
```

For this to work, it assumes that you have the "shortest" version in the data.  So, it won't look for "John" if "John" is not a data row.

Answer (score 0):

how about this?

```
SELECT  Name
FROM    tableName
GROUP   BY Name
HAVING  COUNT(*) > 1
```